# How to sort dict list with multiple key attributes - python

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I am trying to sort list dict based on two key parameters　- "id" and "type". Imagine you have a list like the below

```
dict_list = [
    { "id" : 1, "type" : "snippet", "attribute" :'test'},
    { "id" : 2, "type" : "snippet", "attribute" :'hello'},
    { "id" : 1, "type" : "code", "attribute" : 'wow'},
    { "id" : 2, "type" : "snippet", "attribute" :'hello'},
 ]
```

The end result should be like this.

```
dict_list = [
    { "id" : 1, "type" : "snippet",　"attribute" : 'test'　},
    {　"id" : 2,　"type" : "snippet",　"attribute" :　'hello'　},
    {　"id" : 1,　"type" : "code",　"attribute" : 'wow'　},
]
```

I tried this method but it only produces a unique list based on only "key" attribute.

```
unique_list = {v['id'] and v['type']:v  for v in dict_list}.values()
```

How can I generate a unique list based on two key parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the behavior that you want.  How do you compare two dicts with arbitrary 'id' and 'type' fields?  Do you want to sort by one of the fields first, and if they are the same, then sort by the second field?

Comment: `sorted(...,key=(type,id),reverse=True)` is what he shows in his example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seen_items = set()
filtered_dictlist = (x for x in dict_list 
                     if (x["id"], x["type"]) not in seen_items 
                     and not seen_items.add((x["id"], x["type"])))
sorted_list = sorted(filtered_dictlist,
                     key=lambda x: (x["type"], x["id"]),
                     reverse=True)
```

I think should first filter and then sort it how you want ...

you can use itemgetter to make it more elegant

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_getter = itemgetter("type", "id")
seen_items = set()
filtered_values = [x for x in dict_list 
                   if my_getter(x) not in seen_items 
                   and not seen_items.add(my_getter(x))]
sorted_list = sorted(filtered_dictlist, key=my_getter, reverse=True)
```